# Записать предпоследний клик

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Здравствуйте. Работаю в JQuery, возник такой вопрос, как рациональнее записать предпоследний клик? Вот объяснение, что нужно сделать

```
$(document).on('click', "#elementid a", function() {
    //Нужно сделать следующее. Если юзер кликнул по элементу 2 раза, то выполняем один блок. Если 1 раз или больше 2 - другой блок. Разумеется, без записи предпосленего кликнутого элемента не обойтись
});
```

Comment: счетчик держите, можете в `$(this).data()`;

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastElement = {};
$(document).on('click', "#elementid a", function() {
  if(this == lastElement){
    //код повторного нажатия
  }else{
    //код первого нажатия
  }
  lastElement = this;
});
```